# Practical limitations for postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, size, postgresql-9.5

Questions to Postgres Database Admins,
If we build a table of 30TB, is it practically maintainable considering it has sensor data. Millions of data inserted every minute.
If we build a database of 60TB, is it  practically maintainable?
How difficult to maintain/monitor/scale postgres database to handle large data volume?
What are alternate databases?
Any other suggestions

Comment: How do you define “maintainable”? This is quite a broad question by itself and would need quite a lot more specifics

Comment: maintainable - run a meaningful query to do CRUD operations. Practically possible to maintain, like it shouldn't crash or slow down significantly when we scale up, when  a table goes beyond 30TB of size. Basically looking for some advice/tips/feedbacks from someone who  handled/handling extra large postgres database(>30TB).

Comment: Look at cloud offerings. Amazon offer a range of DB's that could be worth investigating, but like Sami said, without more info of what you are doing/storing we can't offer much advice. https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/

Comment: Sorry, let me try to provide more details.  Say, I have a requirement to create large postgres DB. There will be tables of size 20/30TB. Is it advisable to use postgres or some other DB? My preference will be postgres but i am looking for suggestions.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at [TimescaleDB](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb), which is based on PostgreSQL and was made for exactly your kind of workload. Open source, run your own or managed in a cloud. (No, I don't work for them.)

Comment: hmm, this seems nice. but we are mostly going to deal with sensor data. May be a timeseries but not a real timeseries analysis based data.